# Why is 1 term wrong

Tags: numbers

A module takes __ and the work is very intensive...
The correct answer is "a term" or "one term", I wrote "1 term" and is marked wrong, even though not long after this question "2 modules" is one of the correct answer.

From: from one of the IELTS question.https://ieltscat.xdf.cn/mock/analyze/listen/A5DAEBF566DF7EFC/26

Comment: There is no "right" or "wrong" about whether to write numbers as words or numerals: it is simply a matter of style. As far as I know, most style guides recommend using words for small numbers - so I would expect both "one" and "two" rather than "1" and "2" .

Comment: Ask the person who marked it wrong. They know what their reasoning was, and it is their job to explain it to you. We didn't mark it wrong, and we don't know what their reasoning was.

Comment: It's a question of style, not technical correctness.

Comment: The answer reflects convention: When "one" is used as an emphasised synonym of "a/an" (I have one brother / It takes one term) or as a pronoun to mean "a single item" (I want one!), it is usually written in full, and looks strange when it is not. This restriction does not apply to numbers greater than one, although 1 to 9 are usually written in full. Additionally, numbers are *not* used to start sentences: "1 is a prime number." (This looks awkward), **but** "Count from 1 to 20" is fine as the "1" (and "20") refers only to a pure number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's quite uncommon to write "one" as "1", except when talking about the number "1" itself.

As an example, we might write: "He wrote one number, which was the number 1, and below that he wrote two more numbers, the numbers 2 and 3."

A [Google Ngrams search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=lasted+one+year%2C+lasted+1+year&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clasted%20one%20year%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clasted%201%20year%3B%2Cc0) shows that "lasted one year" is much more common than "lasted 1 year".

I don't think I would say that "A module takes 1 term" is *wrong*, but in most contexts, it looks like lazy writing. "A module takes one term" looks much better.